# mongo insert in nodejs for loop only inserting one from array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

im building an application to collect votes for a live event.

the api doesnt give us option to select users from a time frame so im polling the endpoint every second.

i currently have 13 entries that return from the endpoint, i parse them into and array and for loop around them setting my mongoose schema with the attributes and trying to save them, but when i do

db.votes.count() my result is always 1

my node module looks like

```
var express    = require('express');
var unirest = require('unirest');
var voteSchema = require(GLOBAL.rootdir + '/modules/voting/models/votes');

var seconds = 0;
var interval = 1000;

express({
    votePoller : setInterval(function () {
        seconds++;
        if (typeof GLOBAL.accessToken != 'undefined') {

            var Request = unirest.get('https://api.domain.io/api/v1/guests');
            Request
                .header('Accept', 'application/json')
                .header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
                .header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + GLOBAL.accessToken)
                .end(function (response) {

                    if(response.code === 200){
                        var votesModel = new voteSchema;

                        var payloadArray = JSON.parse(response.raw_body);
                        for(var i in payloadArray.guests){
                            console.log(i);
                            console.log(payloadArray.guests[i]);

                            votesModel.ctid = payloadArray.guests[i].id;
                            votesModel.email = payloadArray.guests[i].username;
                            votesModel.voteStatus = 0;
                            votesModel.createdAt = new Date(1000 * payloadArray.guests[i].created_at);

                            votesModel.save(function(err) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                    console.log({ message: err });
                                } else {
                                    console.log({ message: 'vote saved' });
                                }
                            });
                            console.log('Done');
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
        console.log(seconds);
    }, interval)
});

var votePoller = express;

module.exports = votePoller;
```

my mongoose model is

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var votesSchema = new Schema({
    ctid: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    fullName: { type: String},
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    mobileNumber: { type: String },
    vote:   { type: Number},
    voteStatus: Boolean,
    createdAt: Date
});

var Votes = mongoose.model('Votes', votesSchema);

module.exports = Votes;
```

the console log counts out each i in the array so why the save function isn't being fired is stumping me

Thanks in advance

Comment: you're using a for loop during an asynchronous callback method `save`.. anytime you make a network call, in this case to the db, you need to handle control flow

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an async function to do an async for loop, there are many answer on here for that code.  I would suggest a control flow library like [async](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqg5vkqsrKAhVDuxQKHW66A7YQFgggMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fcaolan%2Fasync&usg=AFQjCNElQtLq1_Chm4lL64fOeW6WqVPMgQ&sig2=WEa2U0QFBv3r30kJcMavGg) or if using a new version of node, use native promises instead.  Promises all method is the best way to achieve this.